# How do I Clear These HUGE Pligg SQL Loads that are Getting my Hosting Suspended

Tags: php, mysql, pligg

```
80765 | localhost | Query | 135 | Locked | UPDATE pligg_links set link_summary='', link_title_url='-165999', link_url='OMIT' |

| 80781 | localhost | Query | 143 | Sending data | SELECT * FROM pligg_links

| 80861 | localhost | Query | 135 | Locked | SELECT link_id, link_category, link_title, link_title_url, COUNT(tag_link_id) AS relevance, tag_link |

| 80872 | localhost | Query | 134 | Locked | SELECT count(*) from pligg_links where link_status = "queued" |
```

This last one goes on & on... same process it seems.  Pligg's support is pretty sparse and I've been trying to solve these issues for days.

Would anyone know an edit I can make either within PHPMyAdmin, a php file or inside Pligg to cut this out?

Secret ninja password: `SHOW CREATE TABLE pligg_links\G`

Thank you!

Comment: Just curious how many rows are in pligg_links?  Is it an InnoDB table?

Comment: pligg_links has about 130k rows. I don't know if it is an InnoDB table; how would I find out?  Thank you

Comment: A `SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'pligg_links'` should show the `ENGINE` which tells you what type.  Probably MyISAM or InnoDB.

Comment: If you also add a `SHOW CREATE TABLE pligg_links\G` to the question as well that could be helpful.

Comment: Asking my host now - did you mean to add that line to my question here on S.O.?

Comment: You can run it from phpMyAdmin.  Yes, if you could add the output from the `SHOW CREATE TABLE pligg_links\G` to the question it could be helpful.

Comment: Ok, adding it now - and I can't even access cPanel, they suspended my account. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the table engine to InnoDB (phpMyAdmin can help you do this), as this lets you use row-level locking.

On top of that, run this immediately after `mysql_connect()`:

```
mysql_query( "SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED");
```

That mouthful will allow `SELECT` queries to run even if an `UPDATE` is running, by reading the rows before they get updated if they have to. In most cases, this is fine - it's only if you're dealing with majorly important issues like ones that involve money that you need to be careful.

Comment: I just want to let you know I successfully did what you suggested; it seems like it may have helped but waiting for confirmation from my host.  Thank you!

Comment: Hello, it appears everything is running well now.  Thank you very much for your help!